# Inserting jQuery with Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, colorbox, drupal-7

I want to use the Colourbox jQuery script on my Drupal 7 site, but I only want it to load on certain content types.

I found [this script][1] that does want I want. It is for Drupal 6, but seems to work perfectly for Drupal 7.

In the script, you have to insert the Java Script inside a PHP wrapper.
However, because my Java Script uses two kinds of quotation marks/apostrophes it breaks the script. How can I correct this?

Here is the script I am trying to use (inserted in template.php):

> function
>   THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables)
>   {
>       // test for resource page node type   if ($variables['type'] ==
>   'resources_page') {
>
> ```
> // include colorbox javascript
> drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js');
>
>
> // include colorbox css
> drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/scripts/colorbox/colorbox.css');  
>    $js = '        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
>       jQuery('.photos>a').attr('rel',
> ```
>
> 'colorbox');
>             jQuery("a[rel='colorbox']").each(function(){
>
> ```
> jQuery(this).colorbox({title:jQuery(this).attr('title')+
> ```
>
> " " + 
>       jQuery(this).find('img').attr('alt')});
>   }); 
>       ';
>       drupal_add_js($js, 'inline');
>          }    }

The bit **jQuery("a[rel='colorbox']").** breaks the script as it has two kinds of quotation marks. How can I fix this?

[1]:   // Add jScript http://thedrupalblog.com/adding-jquery-image-carousel-your-node-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could make use of the [heredoc feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) of PHP, but actually, I would find it more sensible to put your custom JavaScript in its own file and include it with `drupal_add_js`. Just like you did with the colorbox plugin.

```
drupal_add_js('/path/to/your/custom.js/');
```

I think most web applications adhere to the concept of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), that is, separating markup (HTML) from style (CSS) and behaviour (JavaScript) for example. It could ease maintenance, say you have designers on your team that are responsible for HTML/CSS/JS only, you probably don't want them to touch PHP code.

And of course you could escape the quotes.

```
$foo = 'Hello \'Name\'';
$bar = "$('a[rel=\"colorbox\"]')";
```